# Send an email if someone posts a message into a Slack channel

Tags: email, slack

We are using Slack as a team. However, there are also parties that are not part of our team but can participate via a mailing list.

I want to set up a channel in Slack, say `#mailinglist`. Whenever some team member posts a message into this channel I want an email going out to the mailinglist address.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an outgoing email integration for now

Comment: @Sathya Yes. That's the definition of integration though. I thought maybe something could be accomplished using the outgoing webhook. One could hook it up with a mail-sending PHP script.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by using [Slack's WebHook integration](https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks) and let it call a little [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) script I wrote. The script takes the information and mails it.

The script is really simple and [it's on GitHub](https://github.com/kolomanschaft/slack-mailer).

Comment: How did you configure the webhook? Is it a slack command that you run like `/mail This is the email body` or can the mail script be triggered automatically by a keyword in a post?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of Slack's webhook integration and for the example. They worked perfectly for my requirements. Note that you will need to install it once PER-CHANNEL if you do not use keywords to trigger on "any channel". There is no "any channel" selection that will send an e-mail without a keyword (why not is beyond me...) I did try MailClark first but found it difficult to configure, confusing, and only free for one channel and then $9/month after that for each extra channel. Way beyond my budget anyway.

Answer (score 6):

There's a Slack integration for that: [MailClark](https://mailclark.ai). It includes a Group mode, which does exactly what you describe. You can have a Slack channel with any combination of Slack and email users, where Slack messages are sent out as emails, and emails are received as Slack messages.

Comment: support will end with end of 2022 https://mailclark.ai/help/article/9w4m1i908x

Comment: @CodingYourLife indeed. Any alternatives to suggest?

Comment: yes posted my recommendation. in case since 2016 you are now about to migrate check my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This was asked quite some time ago and I think the answers are not accurate anymore. MailClark will put the plug end of 2022 and not sure if the php example is still working.

But I ended checking what's the latest desire for slack how to tackle such a problem and I guess it is a Slack Bolt App: https://api.slack.com/bolt

I can recommend it.

It is surprisingly easy to do a simple text matching that can e.g. reverse your text. So "hello" becomes ""olleh".

E.g. here in Javascript.

```
// Reverse all messages the app can hear
app.message(async ({ message, say }) => {
  // Filter out message events with subtypes (see https://api.slack.com/events/message)
  if (message.subtype === undefined || message.subtype === 'bot_message') {
    const reversedText = [...message.text].reverse().join("");
    await say(reversedText);
  }
});
```

I guess from there it is easy to instead send the text as email (check sendgrid, mailgun, amazon SES) or start a Falcon 9 Rocket.